# PlayFramework: transform json to json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

i have a json like this

```
{
"value.first" : "one",
"value.second" : "two",
"value.third" : "three"
}
```

how do I transform it like this in Scala/Play? :

```
{
  "value": { 
   "first": "one",
   "second": "two",
   "third": "three"
  }  
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out the existing scala frameworks to process Json-Code https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on the necessary flexibility and the handling of wrong json format. Maybe the following will work for you.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val jsonInitial = Json.obj(
  "value.first" -> "one",
  "value.second" -> "two",
  "value.third" -> "three"
)

val primary: String = jsonInitial.keys.headOption
  .map{ _.split('.')(0) }
  .getOrElse("empty")

val secondary: Seq[(String, JsValue)] = jsonInitial.fields
  .map{ case (k, v) => (k.split('.')(1), v) }

val jsonModified = Json.obj(
  primary -> JsObject(secondary)
)
```